# 2007 dodge magnum issues

Tags: battery

The battery light in the car came on, the headlights became very dim, almost as if they were going out. The speedometer would drop down to zero. Most of the dials were going up and down.  When I would I would push on the brakes, it would slow down, but then speed up. Not sure what this is, made it home, but unsure what needs to be done.

Comment: Check all the battery connections, alternator, starter and the ground cables - something sounds loose or broken somewhere...

Comment: Possible bad alternator.